# Set size for segmented control globally?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

Currently in each of my views, I am setting the height of my segmented control in the `viewDidLoad` event like this:

```
mySegmentedControl.frame = CGRect(
  x: mySegmentedControl.frame.origin.x,
  y: mySegmentedControl.frame.origin.y,
  width: mySegmentedControl.frame.size.width,
  height: 22)
```

It works but it's tedious and was hoping I can do this in the `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
var frame = UISegmentedControl.appearance().frame
UISegmentedControl.appearance().frame = CGRect(
  x: frame.origin.x,
  y: frame.origin.y,
  width: frame.size.width,
  height: 22)
```

But this has no effect or even an error, it remains the default height. I even tried to subclass it like this but no effect or error either:

```
class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        sizeThatFits.height = 22
        return sizeThatFits
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or a way to set the height globally?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that :

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes 
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```